# How to capture full scrollable image of the page with Karate compare image tool

Tags: karate

I am trying Karate (https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#compare-image) feature and following the example provided.

What I have noticed where the page contains a scroll bar the image compare only capture the visible part in the view section to image compare [see attached image example of the report of BBC sports page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMA57.png).

How can I capture the full scrollable page to compare the image?

Comment: see if this works, else we would like the community to contribute: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72544735/143475 - I think it may be possible by calling the chrome APIs

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, only what's in the view ports is captured in the screenshot, the rest is just whitespace.